# Generating pyodbc SQL syntax within a loop

Tags: ms-access, pyodbc

Can you do such a thing? I have the following but cursor.execute does not like the syntax of selectSQL. Ultimately I'm looking to iterate through all tables in a .accdb and insert records from each table into a another .accdb with the same tables and fields. Reason being, bringing over new records from field data collection on TabletPCs to master database on server.

```
import pyodbc

connOtherDB = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='path to my dbase;")
otherDBtbls = connOtherDB.cursor().tables()
for t in otherDBtbls:
    if t.table_name.startswith("tbl"): #ignores MS sys tables
        cursor = connOtherDB.cursor()
        #selectSQL = '"SELECT * from '+ str(t.table_name) + '"'
        cursor.execute("SELECT * from tblDatabaseComments") #this works if I refer to a table by name
        cursor.execute(selectSQL) #this does not work. throws SQL syntax error
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row:
            print t.table_name
            print row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)() to ease building of SQL statements:

```
import pyodbc

connOtherDB = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='path to my dbase;")
otherDBtbls = connOtherDB.cursor().tables()
for t in otherDBtbls:
    if t.table_name.startswith("tbl"): #ignores MS sys tables
        cursor = connOtherDB.cursor()
        selectSQL = 'SELECT * FROM {}'.format(t.table_name)
        cursor.execute(selectSQL)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row:
            print t.table_name
            print row
```

As an aside, take a look a [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for guidance on maximum line length and variable naming, among other coding conventions.

Comment: Thanks beargle. Worked like a charm. I'm a python novice if the style didn't give me away ;-). Appreciate the style guide link. I'll look it over and try to improve. An intro course I took told us to use lowerCamelCase, but I guess I didn't even implement that correctly.

Comment: @dgj32784 Glad to hear that it helped. Remember to upvote and accept if the answer was useful and solved your problem.